# Springboard like appearance without Three20 or Nimbus

Tags: ios, three20, aqgridview, springboard

I want to make a button launcher just like Springboard / Facebook / Google+.

But, I don't want to:

- use [Three20](http://three20.info/) - it looks perfect except for the horrid coding experience due to documentation. (I also wonder if it is abandonware, doubt it, but with Nimbus I wonder.)
- use [Nimbus](http://www.ohloh.net/p/nimbus-ios) - it looks like it will be perfect, but not today and I need it now.
- use a stock UI button, with a background image that is transparent at the bottom and move the Title down to that area. - This just seems like a gross hack.

Two possibilities are:
 - AlanQuatermain's [AQGridView](https://github.com/AlanQuatermain/AQGridView) 
 - rigoneri/Jarada's [myLauncher2](https://github.com/Jarada/myLauncher)

Both of these have licenses which permit commercial development and both seem to be actively used. I'll try both of them but I was wondering if I missed any and if there were any gotcha's with either of them.

Oh, I could roll my own button (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1674149/create-a-uibutton-like-the-app-buttons-on-the-springboard-home-screen)) but if there is an open source button out there that would save me some effort. I don't really need the Launcher right now, my app fits on one screen with a spare button slot, but of course it would be nice so I could have room to grow. AQGridView and myLauncher would really have to be bad for me to consider doing that.

Are there any other pitfalls with Nimbus, AQGridView, myLauncher2 that I've not mentioned? Are there any other players in the "Springboard-like" UI framework field?

Thanks!

---

Note: It does appear that I can use Nimbus's Launcher without worrying too much about all the other Nimbus code if I don't want too. Nimbus is very modular, I just need the Core and the Launcher and I satisfy my requirements above. The nice thing about this approach is that as Nimbus matures I can pick and choose the other features from it that I want to use.

---

Comment: Your question don't contains a question.

Comment: I highly recommend AQGridView, so long as you aren't looking for horizontal scrolling.  The example is even a springboard!